# How can I check if the connected SQL Server is on the local machine?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

Is there any way of telling, using C#, if the Sql Server I'm connected to in Ado.Net is on the local machine rather than remote?

I'm wanting to know whether I have access to the file system where SQL Server stores, for example it's backup files. That would let me determine whether I would be able to delete a backup file programatically if I get SQL Server to create one. I have read about xp_cmdshell and such like, but I believe it's best to avoid them.

Comment: Physical machine or virtual machine?
Would the check be performed on the SQL server or from C# code?

Comment: Seems like a weird thing to want to do, i don't really understand why you would care.  Could you explain what you are trying to achive, maybe their is a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`SERVERPROPERTY('MachineName')`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174396.aspx):

> Windows computer name on which the
>   server instance is running.
>
> For a clustered instance, an instance
>   of SQL Server running on a virtual
>   server on Microsoft Cluster Service,
>   it returns the name of the virtual
>   server.

You should not use [`HOST_NAME()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178598.aspx) because that returns the name of the *workstation*, in other words the name of the client, and is *always* going to appear that you're connected locally.

Comment: I've deleted my answer because it is wrong and I don't want other developers to come here and pick up something incorrect by mistake. I didn't look hard enough when I was testing this earlier. Remus' answer is the correct one. If it's possible Samuel, you should mark this as the official answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just check if System.IO.File.Exists = True. Even if the files are on a network, the user may have permission (Or be given permission).